# Android Activity leak in very simple setup

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks

I have a system of 2 ridiculously simple Activity objects - MainActivity starts TestActivity, which has a very large image on it. When in TestActivity, i press back button and get back to MainActivity, however my memory (about 45-50m) doesn't get GCed. Any ideas?

[image: Leak]

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

TestActivity.java

```
    public class TestActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }


    }
```

MainActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.leaked.leaked.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

TestActivity layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/earth_poster_large"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.leaked.leaked">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TestActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it really a memory leak?

Comment: Looks like it is. Did a heap dump and analyzed it in Android Studio. Added pic to question body. Plus, it really isn't garbage collecting that huge chunk of memory (i specifically used a very large image in layout of TestActivity)

Answer (score 0):

You should release the memory occupied by the `ImageView` when you no longer need it. 
In your case, you can do that in TestActivity's `onDestroy()` using this -

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: Ok. Did that. Added:

`((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.huge_image)).setImageDrawable(null);`

It certainly did brind down the allocated memory. However, the activity is still shown under the "Leaked" dropdown of heap dump analyzer in Android Studio.

Comment: I actually added the huge image just to be able to quickly see that memory is being occupied. Before that, i had no image - the TestActivity was leaking back then too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is `destroy` the `activity` by calling `finish()` manually.

But it is still not guaranteed that memory will not be occupied.

Comment: Hm.  I was under the impression that once onDestroy() is called,  and there are no memory leaks (like a static Context or smth like that) the activity is to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there really isn't a leak. If I try to lauch some huge test activity it will successfully display the "leaked activities". I guess Android runtime doesn't gc those activities immediately for performance reasons, i.e. maybe the user will come back to them again in the future. And only if sufficiently long time passes will it gc those stray activities.